# Why my data messing up (different columns) when I exporting from MySQL from workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I exporting my data from MySQL workbench, most of my columns mixed up on my Excel sheet. Can anybody please tell me how to fix it or is there any better way to export data to excel sheet?

How I do it, 
[image]
My result on Excel sheet

[image]

Thank you so much

Comment: Looks to me like you did not export your data to a properly formed CSV file. Open the exported file with a text editor and take a look: some columns with commas or spaces in their values are probably not surrounded by `"Column, disrupted"` quote marks `"`

Comment: Hey, I double check it, and I opened it from notepad. Its look fine to me. Is there any other way to export data?